# ListView Duplicating Data

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

Have an android application that on one of the pages has a `ListView`. The `ListView` has an array with 5 objects in it that is passed into the list adapter to be displayed. On the list view it shows 5 items but the bottom one is shown as a duplicate. However when you click this item it will show the right data that isn't duplicated on another page. Below see the code and screenshots.

**MyJobsFragment.java**

```
private void bidOnList() throws ParseException
{
    final ArrayList<String> jobsListArray = new ArrayList<>();

    // Iterate through entire bids table
    for (DataSnapshot ds : getBidListChildren())
    {
        // Iterate through the actual bids information
        Iterable<DataSnapshot> bidsSnapShot = ds.getChildren();

        for (DataSnapshot ds1 : bidsSnapShot)
        {
            // if the User Id equals the current user added to a list
            if (getBidInformation(ds1).getUserID().equals(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()))
            {
                boolean active = ds1.child("active").getValue(boolean.class);
                if (active)
                {
                    jobsListArray.add(ds.getKey());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Go through the jobs table
    for (DataSnapshot ds3 : getJobListChildren())
    {
        /*
           If the job is in the jobsListArray previously and the status is Pending
            Add to the jobsList
        */
        if (jobsListArray.contains(ds3.getKey()) && getJobInformation(ds3).getJobStatus().equals("Pending"))
        {
            Date sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(genericMethods.getJobInformation(ds3).getCollectionDate());

            if (new Date().before(sdf))
            {
                jobListKey.add(ds3.getKey());
                jobList.add(getJobInformation(ds3));
            }
        }
    }

    // Display information in ListView
    mAdapterBidOn = new MyCustomAdapterForTabViews(getActivity(), isAdded(), host, getLayoutInflater(), getFragmentManager());
    mAdapterBidOn.addKeyArray(jobListKey);
    mAdapterBidOn.addArray(jobList);

    jobListViewBidOn.setAdapter(mAdapterBidOn);

    // Press on the object and go view all the Job Information and Bids
    jobListViewBidOn.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            BidOnJobsFragment bidOnJobsFragment = new BidOnJobsFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("Job", mAdapterBidOn.mData.get(position));
            bundle.putSerializable("JobId", mAdapterBidOn.mDataKeys.get(position));
            bidOnJobsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, bidOnJobsFragment).addToBackStack("tag").commit();
        }
    });
}
```

The above method adds all the relevant data into an array list and adds it into the adapter.

**Custom Adapter**

```
public class MyCustomAdapterForTabViews extends BaseAdapter
{

public ArrayList<JobInformation> mData = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<JobInformation> mDataOrig = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<String> mDataKeys = new ArrayList<>();
private TabHost host;

public LayoutInflater mInflater;
private FragmentActivity fragmentActivity;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;


public MyCustomAdapterForTabViews(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity, boolean isAdded, TabHost host, LayoutInflater layoutInflater, FragmentManager fragmentManager)
{
    if (isAdded)
    {
        this.fragmentActivity = fragmentActivity;
        this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
        this.layoutInflater = layoutInflater;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) fragmentActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    this.host = host;
}

public void addItem(final JobInformation item)
{
    mData.add(item);
    mDataOrig.add(item);
}


public void addArray(final ArrayList<JobInformation> j)
{
    mData.clear();
    mDataOrig.clear();
    mData = j;
    mDataOrig = j;
}

public void addKeyArray(final ArrayList<String> k)
{
    mDataKeys.clear();
    mDataKeys = k;
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return mData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position)
{
    return mData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds()
{
    return false;
}

@Override
public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer)
{

}

@Override
public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer)
{

}

@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled()
{
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    // Bid on holder
    MyCustomAdapterForTabViews.GroupViewHolderBidOn holderBidOn;
    // Accepted holder
    final MyCustomAdapterForTabViews.GroupViewHolderAccepted holderAccepted;
    // Completed holder
    MyCustomAdapterForTabViews.GroupViewHolderCompleted holderCompleted;

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        // Bid on
        if (host.getCurrentTab() == 0)
        {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.job_info_bid_on, null);
            holderBidOn = new MyCustomAdapterForTabViews.GroupViewHolderBidOn();

            holderBidOn.textViewJobName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
            holderBidOn.imageViewCross = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewCross);
            holderBidOn.imageViewEditPen = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewEditPen);
            holderBidOn.textViewJobDescription = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textDesc);
            holderBidOn.textViewAddressFrom = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textAddressFrom);
            holderBidOn.textViewAddressTo = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textAddressTo);

            holderBidOn.textViewJobName.setText(mData.get(position).getAdvertName());
            holderBidOn.textViewJobDescription.setText(mData.get(position).getAdvertDescription());
            holderBidOn.textViewAddressFrom.setText(mData.get(position).getColL1() + ", " + mData.get(position).getColTown() + ", " + mData.get(position).getColPostcode());
            holderBidOn.textViewAddressTo.setText(mData.get(position).getDelL1() + ", " + mData.get(position).getDelPostcode() + ", " + mData.get(position).getDelPostcode());

            holderBidOn.imageViewCross.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    final DatabaseConnections databaseConnections = new DatabaseConnections();

                    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(fragmentActivity);
                    View mView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_creator, null);

                    alertDialog.setTitle("Delete Job");
                    alertDialog.setView(mView);
                    final AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
                    dialog.show();

                    TextView customText = mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCustomText);
                    customText.setText("Are You Sure You Want To Delete " + mData.get(position).getAdvertName() + "?");

                    Button yesButton = mView.findViewById(R.id.yesButton);
                    Button noButton = mView.findViewById(R.id.noButton);

                    yesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view)
                        {
                            // My Adverts
                            if (mData.get(position).getPosterID().equals(databaseConnections.getCurrentUser()))
                            {
                                databaseConnections.getDatabaseReference().child("Jobs").child(mDataKeys.get(position)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                                    {
                                        databaseConnections.getDatabaseReference().child("Jobs").child(mDataKeys.get(position))
                                                .child("jobStatus").setValue("Inactive");
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
                                    {

                                    }
                                });

                                databaseConnections.getDatabaseReference().child("Bids").child(mDataKeys.get(position)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                                    {
                                        databaseConnections.getDatabaseReference().child("Bids").child(mDataKeys.get(position)).child(mData.get(position)
                                                .getCourierID()).child("active").setValue(false);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
                                    {

                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            // My Jobs
                            else
                            {
                                databaseConnections.getDatabaseReference().child("Bids").child(mDataKeys.get(position)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                                    {
                                        databaseConnections.getDatabaseReference().child("Bids").child(mDataKeys.get(position)).child(databaseConnections.getCurrentUser()).child("active").setValue(false);
                                        mData.remove(position);
                                        mDataKeys.remove(position);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
                                    {

                                    }
                                });
                            }

                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    noButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view)
                        {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            DatabaseConnections databaseConnections = new DatabaseConnections();

            // My Adverts
            if (mData.get(position).getPosterID().equals(databaseConnections.getCurrentUser()))
            {
                holderBidOn.imageViewEditPen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {
                        GenericMethods genericMethods = new GenericMethods();
                        PostAnAdvertFragment postAnAdvertFragment = new PostAnAdvertFragment();

                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putSerializable("JobInfo", mData.get(position));
                        bundle.putSerializable("JobIdKey", mDataKeys.get(position));
                        postAnAdvertFragment.setArguments(bundle);

                        genericMethods.beginTransactionToFragment(fragmentManager, postAnAdvertFragment);
                    }
                });
            }
            // My Jobs
            else
            {
                holderBidOn.imageViewEditPen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            convertView.setTag(holderBidOn);
        }
        // Accepted
        else if (host.getCurrentTab() == 1)
        {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.job_info_accepted, null);
            holderAccepted = new MyCustomAdapterForTabViews.GroupViewHolderAccepted();

            holderAccepted.textViewJobName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
            holderAccepted.textViewDescription = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textDesc);
            holderAccepted.textViewAddressFrom = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textAddressFrom);
            holderAccepted.textViewAddressTo = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textAddressTo);
            holderAccepted.textViewBid = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textBid);

            holderAccepted.textViewJobName.setText(mData.get(position).getAdvertName());
            holderAccepted.textViewDescription.setText(mData.get(position).getAdvertDescription());
            holderAccepted.textViewAddressFrom.setText(mData.get(position).getColL1() + ", " + mData.get(position).getColTown() + ", " + mData.get(position).getColPostcode());
            holderAccepted.textViewAddressTo.setText(mData.get(position).getDelL1() + ", " + mData.get(position).getDelPostcode() + ", " + mData.get(position).getDelPostcode());

            DatabaseConnections databaseConnections = new DatabaseConnections();
            databaseConnections.getDatabaseReference().child("Bids").child(mDataKeys.get(position)).child(mData.get(position).getCourierID()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                    String acceptedBid = dataSnapshot.child("userBid").getValue(String.class);
                    holderAccepted.textViewBid.setText("£" + acceptedBid);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
                {

                }
            });

            convertView.setTag(holderAccepted);
        }
        // Completed
        else if (host.getCurrentTab() == 2)
        {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.job_info_list_completed, null);

            holderCompleted = new MyCustomAdapterForTabViews.GroupViewHolderCompleted();

            holderCompleted.textViewJobName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
            holderCompleted.imageViewCross = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewCross);

            holderCompleted.textViewJobName.setText(mData.get(position).getAdvertName());
            holderCompleted.imageViewCross.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    final DatabaseConnections databaseConnections = new DatabaseConnections();

                    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(fragmentActivity);
                    View mView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_creator, null);

                    alertDialog.setTitle("Delete Job");
                    alertDialog.setView(mView);
                    final AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
                    dialog.show();

                    TextView customText = mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCustomText);
                    customText.setText("Are You Sure You Want To Delete " + mData.get(position).getAdvertName() + "?");

                    Button yesButton = mView.findViewById(R.id.yesButton);
                    Button noButton = mView.findViewById(R.id.noButton);

                    yesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view)
                        {
                            // My Adverts
                            if (mData.get(position).getPosterID().equals(databaseConnections.getCurrentUser()))
                            {
                                databaseConnections.getDatabaseReference().child("Jobs").child(mDataKeys.get(position)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                                    {
                                        databaseConnections.getDatabaseReference().child("Jobs").child(mDataKeys.get(position))
                                                .child("jobStatus").setValue("Inactive");
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
                                    {

                                    }
                                });

                            }
                            // My Jobs
                            else
                            {
                                databaseConnections.getDatabaseReference().child("Bids").child(mDataKeys.get(position)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                                    {
                                        databaseConnections.getDatabaseReference().child("Bids").child(mDataKeys.get(position)).child(databaseConnections.getCurrentUser()).child("active").setValue(false);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
                                    {

                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    noButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view)
                        {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            convertView.setTag(holderCompleted);
        }
    } else
    {
        if (host.getCurrentTab() == 0)
        {
            holderBidOn = (MyCustomAdapterForTabViews.GroupViewHolderBidOn) convertView.getTag();
        } else if (host.getCurrentTab() == 1)
        {
            holderAccepted = (MyCustomAdapterForTabViews.GroupViewHolderAccepted) convertView.getTag();
        } else if (host.getCurrentTab() == 2)
        {
            holderCompleted = (MyCustomAdapterForTabViews.GroupViewHolderCompleted) convertView.getTag();
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}

public class GroupViewHolderBidOn
{
    public TextView textViewJobName;
    public TextView textViewJobDescription;
    public TextView textViewAddressFrom;
    public TextView textViewAddressTo;
    public ImageView imageViewCross;
    public ImageView imageViewEditPen;
}

public class GroupViewHolderAccepted
{
    public TextView textViewJobName;
    public TextView textViewDescription;
    public TextView textViewAddressFrom;
    public TextView textViewAddressTo;
    public TextView textViewBid;
}

public class GroupViewHolderCompleted
{
    public TextView textViewJobName;
    public ImageView imageViewCross;
}

public void filter(String charText)
{
    ArrayList<JobInformation> jobs = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<JobInformation> jA = new ArrayList<>();
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());

    if (charText.length() == 0)
    {
        mData = mDataOrig;
    } else
    {
        for (JobInformation j : mDataOrig)
        {
            if (j.getWholeString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))
            {
                jobs.add(j);
                jA.add(j);
            } else
            {
                jA.add(j);
            }
        }
        mData.clear();
        mData = jobs;
        mDataOrig = jA;
    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

[My Bids 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YW5d.png)

[My Bids 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GDvd.png)

[When you click the bottom Panasonic TV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3EeC.png)

More code can be provided if needed.

**EDIT**

Code runs as intended until it hits the 4th element in the array, once that point is hit, it goes off into base java classes that I'm guessing are for the adapter. It is as if its ignoring the last two and recycling the views.

Comment: Also add code of Activity class where you initialise `MyCustomAdapterForTabViews`.

Comment: Use `HashSet` instead of `ArrayList`.

Comment: Added it in, shouldn't be a problem with the arraylist as the list has the right data in it, will run in debug mode and show you what is in the array

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return 0;
}
```

i think problem is in your above adapter method. change this to below :

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}
```

Comment: Tried it but didnt think it would make a difference, as it is getting the item from the getItem method which returns all the data from that position

Comment: No it didn't unfortunately

Comment: i think you need to send me whole project to analysis. because all your conditions in adapter i can't understand. because its your business logic. so you should to describe all your business logic in in question. with firebase database structure

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, one of the lads in my team, had refactored the code but had moved the catch null exception in the wrong place which was making anything outside the bounds of the viewable array wasn’t been created and was recycling from the top